# telegram bot send request to the server and follow the url

Tags: telegram-bot

Now I am writing a telegram bot and add inline keyboard to each message of my bot.

In my bot I have a reply button which should send request to my webhook and after that follow user to a specific webpage. Is it possible?

1)If i use inline keyboard I only get callback to my webhook. But user is not redirected to an external url

'reply_markup' => json_encode(array(
'inline_keyboard' => array(
array(
array(
'text' => 'Button 1',
'callback_data' => 'test_2',
)
)
),
)),

2. I can use url button. But in this case my webhook is not notified when user clicks this button.

'reply_markup' => json_encode(array(
'inline_keyboard' => array(
array(
array(
'text' => 'Button 1',
'url' => 'http://',
)
)
),
)),

Do you have any idea how do i get notified to the my webhook and after that redirect user to a web page ?

Thanks